# Comparing digits of integers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, int, nested

I am trying to compare the digits of two integers to tell if they have distinct digits or not. **I am having trouble on my hasDistinctIntegers method. It doesn't often evaluate to what it should. True if the number does not have repeating digits, false if it does.** I believe my other methods are working correctly, but I could really use another set of eyes! Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(hasDistinctDigits(12345));
}

public static boolean hasDistinctDigits(int number) {
    boolean returner = true;
    int count1 = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int curNum = number;
    while (count1 < numDigits(number)) {
        int count2 = 0;
        digit = getDigit(curNum, count1);
        curNum = curNum / 10;
        while (count2 < numDigits(curNum)) {
            if (digit == getDigit(curNum, count2)) {
                returner = false;
            }
            count2++;
        }
        count1++;

    }

    return returner;
}

public static int numDigits(int number) {
    int count = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static int getDigit(int number, int i) {
    int digit = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int originalNum = number;

    while (count <= i) {
        if (count == i) {
            digit = number % 10;
        }
        number /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    if (i > numDigits(originalNum)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return digit;
    }
}

public static int indexOf(int number, int digit) {
    int count = 0;
    int index = -1;
    while (count < numDigits(number)) {
        if (getDigit(number, count) == digit) {
            index = count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips/advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Set<Integer>` you can code this as such:

```
public static boolean hasDistinctDigits(int number)
{
    final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    while (number > 0) {
        if (!set.add(number % 10))
            return false;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can also use a plain array:

```
public static boolean hasDistinctDigits(int number)
{
    // We rely on Java's default values here:
    // uninitialized ints will be set to 0.
    final int[] digits = new int[10];
    // But for peace of mind, we can...
    Arrays.fill(digits, 0);

    int digit;

    while (number > 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        if (digits[digit]++ > 0)
            return false;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please note that both methods above don't check whether their argument is greater than 0.

---

Using Java 8, you can even have more fun:

```
public static boolean hasDistinctDigits(int number)
{
    final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    return String.valueOf(number).chars().allMatch(set::add);
}
```

But at this level, this is intellectual masturbation, really... (or (Int)`Stream` abuse -- your pick)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, however the solution is limited to the number of floating digits that a double.
this is the code

```
public int Comparable(double x, int elev, int max){
    // Retorna el digito mas pequegno de un numero dado
    if (elev == 0){
        return max;
    }else {
        int aux = (int) (x*10);
        x = x * 10;
        elev--;
        
        if (max > (int)(x - aux)){
            max = (int)(x - aux);
        }
        
        return Comparable(x, elev, max);
    }
}


public int LessDigit(double x){
    // Dado un numero x el arreglo devolvera el digito menor de dicha 
    //entrada
    int numb = 0;
    while(x > 10){
        x = x/10;
        numb++;
    }
    // Se transforma el numero para un comparacion mas facil
    return Comparable(x, numb, (int)(x));
}
```